# php5 and jQuery ajax return function results

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I'm not sure how to return php function results to a jQuery ajax request my functions.js file has the following function in it:

```
 var PartNumber = "123456890";
 $.ajax({url: 'aoiprocedures?Action=loadparsedata&FullPartNumber=' + PartNumber,
    success: function(oData){
       alert(oData);
 }});
```

and my aoiprocedures.php file has the following in it:

```
<?php
  $pcAction = isset( $_REQUEST['Action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['Action'] : "";
  $FullPartNumber = isset( $_REQUEST['FullPartNumber'] ) ? $_REQUEST['FullPartNumber'] : 0 ;
  switch($pcAction){
        case "loadparsedata":
              $GenerateMsg = DoParseFile($FullPartNumber);
        break;
  }

  function DoParseFile($FullPartNumber){
     //do a bunch of stuff//
     return $FullPartNumber ;
  };
 ?>
```

so, for test purposes, I should be getting back in my javascript alert() box "1234567890" but I'm getting "" (blank).  Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As CoolStraw has already said, ajax sees as response exactly the same thing you see in the browser. So unless you print something out, you will get a blank response.

So...

Change:

```
return $FullPartNumber ;
```

To:

```
echo $FullPartNumber ;
```

Also change:

```
$GenerateMsg = DoParseFile($FullPartNumber);
```

To:

```
DoParseFile($FullPartNumber);
```

Comment: No. I'd say echo $GenerateMsg

Comment: @CoolStraw I agree unless something has been omitted

Answer (score 2):

You have to **echo** or **print** your result. The content that comes out of your php file as in when you visit it via browser is the result that's gonna be received by your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var PartNumber = "123456890";

$.post("aoiprocedures", { my_action: "loadparsedata", FullPartNumber: PartNumber} , success: function(oData){
   alert(oData);
```

} );

```
</script>


<?php

  function DoParseFile($FullPartNumber){
     //do a bunch of stuff//
     echo $FullPartNumber ;
  };

  $pcAction = isset( $_POST['my_action'] ) ? $_REQUEST['my_action'] : "";
  $FullPartNumber = isset( $_REQUEST['FullPartNumber'] ) ? $_REQUEST['FullPartNumber'] : 0 ;
  switch($pcAction){
        case "loadparsedata":
              $GenerateMsg = DoParseFile($FullPartNumber);
        break;
  }
 ?>
```